# Anaconda environment creation

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda

I am new to python and machine learning. I am trying to create separate anaconda environments for tensorflow, keras, etc. in my Windows machine. I have successfully installed anaconda with automatic environment path setup. Created a test environment but when I try to create another one I get the following error. I have python 3.6.2 and 3.7.2 installed in conda. When I write the command 
`conda create -n t_tensor`
it gives the following error. Not sure where the problem is. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Error Image

[image]

Comment: Can you post your path when you run conda.  It will work with the version of python that comes with conda - not the versions that have been installed but that version must be on your path.  Edit your question, cut and paste the path, don't post an image.

Comment: The anaconda you've installed is 64-bit.  Are your python distributions 32 or 64-bit?